# Get dimensions of a HTML5 canvas graphic (Arc), when an event occurs

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, canvas, html5-canvas

My question is: how should I do the logical and mathematical part, in order to calculate the position of each arc, when an event is emitted: "click", "mouseover", etc.

**Points to consider:**

**.** Line width

**.** They are rounded lines.

**.** Arc length in percentage.

**.** Which element is first, ej: z-index position.

[My source code](https://gist.github.com/Hume3/3e50a4afb5c66c82ad61966892fdf827)

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a convenient [`isPointInStroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInStroke) method, just for that.

To take the z-index into consideration, just check in the reverse order you drew:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const centerX = canvas.width/2;
const centerY = canvas.height/2;
const rad = Math.min(centerX, centerY) * 0.75;
const pathes = [
  {
    a: Math.PI/4,
    color: 'white'
  },
  {
    a: Math.PI/1.5,
    color: 'cyan'
  },
  {
    a: Math.PI,
    color: 'violet'
  },
  {
    a: Math.PI*2,
    color: 'gray'
  }
];
pathes.forEach(obj => {
  const p = new Path2D();
  p.arc(centerX, centerY, rad, -Math.PI/2, obj.a-Math.PI/2);
  obj.path = p;
});

ctx.lineWidth = 12;
ctx.lineCap = 'round';

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // since we sorted first => higher z-index
  for(let i = pathes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    let p = pathes[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = p.hovered ? 'green' : p.color;
    ctx.stroke(p.path);
  };
}
function checkHovering(evt) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  let found = false;
  pathes.forEach(obj => {
    if(found) {
      obj.hovered = false;
    }
    else {
      found = obj.hovered = ctx.isPointInStroke(obj.path, x, y);
    }
  });
  draw();
}

draw();
canvas.onmousemove = canvas.onclick = checkHovering;
```

```css
canvas{background: lightgray}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And if you need IE support, [this polyfill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) should do.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to "remember" the objects you drew, rather than drawing them and trying to gather what they are *from* what you drew. So, for example, you could store the render information: (I don't know typescript)

```
let curves = [{start: 30, length: 40, color: "white"}/*...*/];
```

Then, render it:

```
ctx.fillStyle = curve.color;
ctx.arc(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, RADIUS, percentToRadians(curve.start), percentToRadians(curve.start + curve.length));
```

Then, to retrieve the information, simply reference `curves`. The `z` values depend on the order of the render queue (`curves`).

Of course, you probably **could** gather that data from the canvas, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion you are right, I would also avoid creating new object in each iteration, but it is just a quick example, they are gathered because, I was adding a property of "z-index" and I was going to draw them in the correct time. 
I will try to make it simpler to focus on the problem that I need to solve.

Comment: @Hume I don't think I understand you, but yes, you can also store a `zIndex` property and sort the array but that.

Comment: Excuse my english, we are talking about the same, that was the goal of the function "drawArcs", if you look at the code create a property called "index", but i do not finish creating the functionality yet, that's why I draw them one behind the other, haha. https://gist.github.com/Hume3/3e50a4afb5c66c82ad61966892fdf827#file-balancer-ts-L26